# OneNote API - How to download an entire NoteBook?

Tags: c#, onenote, onenote-api

I am working at proofing out the ability to download an entire `OneNote NoteBook` which is located in my personal `OneDrive`. According to the `OneNote API` docs:

> **Important**! To interact with OneNote content and resources, you should always use the OneNote API. Don't use the OneDrive API.

I am trying to find docs or an example of how the to leverage the `OneNote API` to download an entire `NoteBook`.

Comment: What do you intend to do with the notebook once downloaded? How will you open/parse it?

Comment: @JorgeAguirre well currently I have proofed out the ability to download a `OneNote NoteBook` using the `OneDrive SDK` and downloading the stream. However - since a `OneNote NoteBook` is not made up of just a single file, but instead is a combination of many files - I wanted to see if there was a way to leverage the `OneNote API` in order to see if the API supports download and if it will wrap the loose files into a single file.

Comment: Got it. Once you download the entire notebook, what do you intend to do with it? I'm asking to see if there's an API you could use instead, like our import/export API

Comment: @JorgeAguirre I am collecting OneDrive files including OneNote files for the purpose of e-discovery.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of downloading the notebook, I'd encourage you to crawl the notebook content using the OneNote API. Here:

```
GET ~/notebooks?$expand=sections
```

for each section

```
GET ~/sections/id/pages
```

for each page

```
GET ~/page/id/content
```

This will give you the content in the notebook without the need of downloading and parsing (not sure how you were planning to parse the section files offline).